# how to change class after scroll somewhere

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need my header to change its color after scroll. I know there are a lot of questions with a similar problem on Stackoverflow, but I have tried all the solutions and none work. Can someone help me please?

HTML

```
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.header .change {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll >= 500) {
        $(".header").addClass(".change");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass(".change");
    }
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this way,

- set minimum height in css for body `min-height` to activate window scrolling.
- remove `.` from your `addClass()`, like this`addClass('header')` or `removeClass('header')`;
- remove extra `.header` class form `.change` css class

  //CSS

  ```
  body{
   min-height:800px;
   }
  .header{
      background-color: red;
      color: black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
  }

  .change{  //see here 
      background-color: black;
      color: red;
  }
  ```

  //js

  ```
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   //console.log(scroll);
  if (scroll >= 50) {
      //console.log('a');
      $(".header").addClass("change");
  } else {
      //console.log('a');
      $(".header").removeClass("change");
  }
  ```

  });

**SEE DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/12/

**EDIT:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $("#change_header");
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    if (scroll > objectPosition) {
        $(".header").addClass("change");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("change");
    }
});
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/17/

Comment: Thanks so much. And could I ask you one more question? When I need i to change its color after scroll reach some object like it's here in updated JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/14/ . I tried to change scroll position "50" into "#objects_id" but it's not working

Comment: Try `if (scroll > $('#change_header').offset().top ) { }` https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/15/

Comment: @PetrRajchert, Sorry for being late, i was on the way of weekend party with friends, see my updated answer.may it will help as your requirement. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 500) {
        $(".header").addClass("change"); // you don't need to add a "." in before your class name
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("change");
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.change{ // you don't need .header .change
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/6/

Answer (score 1):

**First.** First of all you need to give `min-height` so, user can scroll.

**Second:** Then change `$(".header").addClass(".change");` to `$(".header").addClass("change");`

**Third** And remove `.header` from `.header .change`

Apply following CSS:

```
body{
    min-height:1000px;
}
.header{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

 .change{
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.header .change {
```

to this:

```
.header.change {
```

Note that I removed the space. When you want to indicate multiple styles on the SAME element there should not be a space. The space indicates you are targeting a style on a child element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(".header").html(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".header").addClass("change");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("change");
    }
});
```

Css will be

```
.change{
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the lin[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bwe33x/13/)k here

jquery is

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $(".header").addClass("change");   // removed the . from class
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("change");  // removed the . from class
    }
});
```

css

```
.header{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
 position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

.header.change{
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
.conetnt
{
 height :800px;     // this is just for scroll
}
```

html

```
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="conetnt">    // added this just to enable scrol

</div>
```